# Gradle custom exception causing build failures

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to throw a custom `Exception` in one of my task as shown below

```
task('myRandomTask', type: Zip) {
    if(!(new File("$projectDir/../../some-other-dir/")).exists()) {
        throw new GradleException("dependent dir not kept at relative path");
    }
    //do my stuff
}
```

The problem is when I run `./gradlew build` it fails. Please note `build` target is independent of `myRandomTask` task.

How, I should be sure that this exception must only block execution of this task only when given conditions aren't satisfied and for other non relevant task it should not affect?

Comment: can you post the output of " ./gradlew :myRandomTask --dry-run "

Answer (score 0):

please see docs - for task definitions. specific 'execute' actions should be in doLast  {} or doFirst{}.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:hello_world

in your case

```
task('myRandomTask', type: Zip) {
    doLast {
        if(!(new File("$projectDir/../../some-other-dir/")).exists()) {
            throw new GradleException("dependent dir not kept at relative path");
        }
    }
}
```